# Laravel Migrations - Issues while creating timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I am trying to run migrations on my Laravel instance. They are just the default migrations (users and password resets) but when it tries to make the timestamps it  throws this error:

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'created_at' (SQL: create table `
 users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) n
 ot null, `password` varchar(60) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp default 0 not
 null, `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)
```

as well as a PDOException:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'created_at'
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: In the `created_at` coloumn you had any default value ? You should not have it !! You should have only the datetime coloumn as its datatype

Comment: read this https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/137

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to MySQL not accepting zero as a valid default date and thus the table creation fails a constraint check on creation.

You probably have [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) enabled in your MySQL configuration. Setting this to off will allow you to create the table or alternatively remove the default 0 value or change it to [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp).

You can find out more about this exact issue here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3602

Answer (score 21):

I have been facing the same error. Given solutions does work properly still i want to help laravel developers.
Simply add a following line to config/database.php

```
'mysql' => array(
   'strict'    => true
),
```

Comment: Whilst using a Laravel derived app (Snipe-IT), this solved my problem. Much cleaner than the other choices.

Comment: I had to set `'strict'` to `false`, but it worked all the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

it sounds like strict mode.

You may disable strict mode in one of two ways:

Open your my.ini file within the MySQL installation directory, and look for the text sql-mode.

Find:

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

and change to

sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

or you can run the following in phpMyAdmin

SET @@global.sql_mode='';

Answer (score 4):

This is due to MySQL not accepting zero as a valid default date  so you can write

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
```

or `$table->nullableTimestamps();`

Instead of `$table->timestamps();`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me after being unsuccessful with strict mode:

```
$table->timestamp('published_on')->useCurrent();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following method:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

Really worked!

Answer (score 0):

Migrating old tables works like that:

```
Schema::table(
            'table',
            function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dateTime('created_at')->nullable()->default(NULL)->change();
                $table->dateTime('updated_at')->nullable()->default(NULL)->change();
            }
        );
```

from https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3602

Answer (score 0):

you should disable MySQL strict mode on Laravel.
MySQL has had a strict mode since 5.1, but in 5.7 it became the default.
In Laravel, you can fix this in code: edit your `database.php` config file, and add a key of `strict` with a value of `false`.

**for non-Laravel users:**

if you're using a non-Laravel application,you won't have that option.Here's how to disable strict mode globally.find your MySQL configuration file `my.cnf` or `my.ini` 
the default MySQL configuration will live in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

open the file and find the `[mysqld]` section.We're going to add a new key, `sql_mode`
On MySQL 5.7, the default values for this key out of the box are:

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

The strict mode comes from `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`. So, let's overwrite the `sql_mode` to:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

That's it! Save the file, and restart **MySQL**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nullableTimestamps() instead of timestamps()

or else

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

also, check the **database server version**

Please have a look on these ref links:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3602

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/syntax-error-or-access-violation-1067-invalid-default-value-for-created-at

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL 5.7.28**

[The MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) recommend the following (note the use of `GLOBAL`):

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```