# Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'created_at'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I install laravel 5.5 and When I run `php artisan migrate` show me this error

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQ
>     L: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

And I add below code on `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
 public function boot()
{
     Schema::defaultStringLength(191); //Solved by increasing StringLength
}
```

And then show me this error

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'created_at' (SQL: create table 
>     `password_resets` (`email` varchar(191) not null, `token` varchar(191) not null, `created_at` timestamp not null) de
>     fault character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

Comment: after setting `defaultStringLength`, did you rollback (dropped) the tables ?

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: Did you deleted old db contents?

Comment: @JigarShah Yes I delete database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555844/laravel-migrations-issues-while-creating-timestamps/30555920#30555920

Comment: @GauravRai mysql5.6.17

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3602

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `nullableTimestamps()` instead of `timestamps()`

or

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

also check the **database server version**

Please have a look on these ref links:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3602

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/syntax-error-or-access-violation-1067-invalid-default-value-for-created-at

Answer (score 15):

I'm currently using laravel 7.

I just go to config/database.php

Then I change `strict => true` to `strict => false`.

Then run the same migration again. It works.

Answer (score 7):

my case

```
        $table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable()->default(null);
```

this worked